# GNOME Shell crashing with 'purple haze' effect

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, graphics, gnome

I've just got GNOME with 11.10 up and running with my netbook, and liked it so much I thought I'd get my parents' old machine sorted with Ubuntu too. Unity works fine but when I try to switch to GNOME Shell, I get problems. On login, the wallpaper appears as normal but then the colour bleeds out from the centre, leaving traces of it around the edge in a purple haze (yes, I do like Jimi Hendrix but I'm not making this up).

When I go to Applications, typing then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search field dumps me out so there's nothing but File / Edit / View etc in top left; starting a program seems to work but then there's only a white screen and no program window.

GNOME Classic works fine, from the limited use I've given it. I'm using an Asus desktop with ABIT motherboard, 2.6ghz with 1gb RAM; I've checked drivers and it says I'm up to date, Nvidia graphics. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).